# How to Integrate AIMLBot into C#?

Tags: c#, integration, aiml

I decided to take a look into AIML (Artificial Intelligence Markup Language), I thought it was available for C#, as I have seen a few other people that used AIML in their C# programs, chatbots and so on. Then I noticed something called AIMLBot (Program#) and sure, yeah, referenced it into Visual Studio and all those stuff. But now, I don't know where to start.. There is no documention/tutorial/blahblah for it whatsoever (the original tutorial it had is now down for some reason), whenever I search for 'AIML C#' or anything like that, I get absolutely no search results related to that. Thus leaving me with no guideance on how to use it, whatsoever (since no tutorials/no examples (the sample projects it had with it don't load up anymore, they are from an older version, so Visual Studio doesn't really seem to like it)/no nothing related to it, except for its SourceForge page which contains minimal to no helpful information. So, perhaps what I'm asking for, is a small base, which will get me going.

Thanks,

Comment: I'd start with the Object Browser (under the view menu) which should at least let you see classes, methods and properties. Failing that, grab the Program# source code and dive in. I'd normally recommend starting with the unit tests as they're often a clean way to find functionality, but unfortunately, they're [present but not implemented](http://sourceforge.net/p/aimlbot/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/UnitTests/Bot.cs).

Comment: @Basic The program itself is under 'active development', and it has nearly no guides or whatsoever about it. But its probably the only thing as close as AIML and C# can get. I will do the first thing you said through (object browser). Thanks.